# Is it possible to add a person to an existing LLC?

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, s-corporation, virginia

I have an existing LLC of which I am the sole owner/agent. I would like to add my spouse to the LLC as the second owner/agent. My reason for doing this is because I would like to file taxes for the company as S-corp.

I am in Virginia so I looked at the forms available: http://www.scc.virginia.gov/clk/dom_llc.aspx and the only one that makes sense is http://www.scc.virginia.gov/publicforms/324/llc10111.pdf

However, from that form it seems that a new person can not be added to an existing LLC.

Do I have other options or is my only option to create a new LLC with both of our names?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. You don't need to inform the VA state department about the change. Registered agent (is that what you refer to as "agent"?) doesn't have to be a member, and you can only have one.

It has nothing to do with being taxed as S-Corp **at all**. Totally unrelated and I can't see how you made the connection.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant when I said "agent". If I don't need to inform VA state department then how do I add a new owner to the LLC. I made the connection with S-Corp because I assume while filing taxes for the company as S-corp both people have to be registered as owners of the LLC.

Comment: @josh - you just prepare an operating agreement and have all the members sign on it. Again - has nothing to do with S-Corp, single member LLC can file as S-Corp just as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add and remove what are referred to as 'members.'  This is typically done through an Annual Report Filing or an amendment thereof. Call the state or have a service help you do it.